# SwiftUI onTapGesture: Get both local and global location

Tags: swiftui

Is there is way to get both the global AND local location of a tap through `onTapGesture`? It seems I can only get either:

```
.onTapGesture { location in
        print("Local location: \(location)")
}

.onTapGesture(coordinateSpace: .global) { location in
        print("Global location: \(location)")
}
```

Effectively I try to get the origin of the view. I know the size of the view but not its origin, so could calculate it if I had both locations.